# Javascript PHP synchronisation problem

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want to call a javascript function with parametars that are stored in MySQL. All this is happening on an onClick event.

Here is the javascript code:

```
    function getFile() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {              
    AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();              
  } else {                                  
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (AJAX) {
     AJAX.open("POST", "gmap.php", false);                             
     AJAX.send("searchField=" + searchField.value);
     return load(AJAX.responseText);   

  } else {
     return false;
  }                                             
}
```

So, the gmap.php is echoing the parameters for the javascript load function. But it doesn't load the parameter because the function is called before the MySQL query in gmap.php is executed. I've tried sync and async AJAX. 
If I try to call the javascript function from PHP, it doesn't get executed, because it is called on a onClick event, and this is inside a div.
Please help me, I'm doing this over a week now. I've tried everything.

Here is the php code with the MySQL query:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
$a = $_POST['searchField'];
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "*******";
$dbpass = "*******";
$dbname = "citydb";



    //connect sql
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    //select db
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    //retrieve data
//$city=$_GET['city'];
    //escape user input to help prevent SQL injection
//$city=mysql_real_escape_string($city);
    //query
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$result=mysql_query("SELECT citystart, cityend FROM cityids WHERE city='$a' ");
if(!result) {

    die("Database query failed: " . myql_error());
    }

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


    $lat=$row['citystart'];
    $lng=$row['cityend'];


}


    echo $lat;
    echo ", ";
    echo $lng;



?>
```

Comment: Did you tried using alert() instead of Load()

Comment: Use jQuery for your ajax stuff. Both you and anyone dealing with your code in the future will hate you for doing AJAX without a library encapsulating it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Why? Using jQuery may conflict with other frameworks - MooTools in my experience: thats why I hate using JS frameworks without really good reason and writing anybrowser AJAX is IMO very simple.

Comment: Because it's much more readable? And jQuery was just an example;

Comment: I have never used jQuery, and I think that this is not to complex for handling without jQuery, but anyway if you can tell me how to solve this with jQuery I woul appreciate it

Comment: @Satya Prakash if i try alert(AJAX.responseText) instead of load(AJAX.responseText) it doesn't pass me the MySQL values. However if i define the variable and assing a value to it before the MySQL query, then the alert(AJAX.responseText) passes the right value. So the problem is that the load function should wait for MySQL to execute the query. Do you have any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

pass the php url together with the variable to search.

```
if (AJAX) {
     var url = "gmap.php?searchField="+ searchField.value;
     AJAX.open("POST", "url", false);                             
     AJAX.send(true);
     return load(AJAX.responseText);   
}
```

Comment: No. This would work if you used GET method, gmap.php recieves empty POST. Have you tested it? I would be quite surprised if it works in any browser.

Comment: I've solved the problem wich concernes passing the searchField data to PHP. My problem is pasing the PHP data to javascript. My javascript function loads before the MySQL query is executed. Do you have any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think searchField.value does not contain anything.

Replace

```
searchField.value
```

With this

```
document.getElementById('searchField').value
```

assign the searchField as an id to the search box.

Comment: I've assigned it, and PHP gets the value, so this part is ok. But PHP doesn't pass the result back to javascript before the javascript function is executed. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this code after AJAX.open and before AJAX.send.

```
AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-length", searchField.value.length);
AJAX.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

I have succesfully tested this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function load(response) {
  alert(response);
}

function getFile() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();              
  else AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  if (AJAX) {
    var params = "foo=" + searchField.value;
    AJAX.open("POST", "http://localhost/test.php", true);                             
    AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    AJAX.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var ok;
      try { ok=AJAX.readyState; } catch(e) { }
      if(ok==4) load(AJAX.responseText);
    }
    AJAX.send(params);
  }                                             
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="searchField"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="getFile()"/>
<script>
  searchField = document.getElementById("searchField");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It also doesn't work sadly. It doesn't get the MySQL values. while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


 $lat=$row['citystart'];
 $lng=$row['cityend'];


}

 echo $lat;
 echo ", ";
 echo $lng;
it returns me only the string ", " without the $lat and $lng values. However if i define the values before the MySQL query (for example: $lat=11, $lng=10) than it returns the string "11, 10". So the question is how to force javascript to wait for the MySQL values?

Comment: It passes the POST vars to script, I have tested it in FireFox and Chrome. Edit your initial message, paste here your MySQL script in gmap.php: it seems something is wrong there.

Comment: I've editet my post. So i have in my SQL table the coordinates with wich i want to load the google map (the load funcion). I want to pass the SQL values to represent the data for google.maps.LatLng().

Comment: Have you tested your PHP script?  It looks like that's the real problem here, not the javascript.  If you're getting back a "," then the script is getting called but is not returning a proper value.

Comment: Same problem, it doesn't even show "ok". But the PHP file seems fine, because if i load gmap.php in my browser it shows data. I'm going insane with this...

Comment: I assume you feed POST["searchField"] to gmap.php when you tested it in the browser. Try to echo your mysql query. If it is correct (the '$a' is not missing) and it is still not working, then I do not know why. Please write here if you find it out. Good luck.

Comment: I changed the $a in the SQL query for the test in the browser. The gmap.php. The problem is with the synchronisation with the javascript function, because the function exectutes before it gets the php parameter. Maybe there is anoter option to wait for javascript for the php to finish? As mentioned earlier, I also tried to call the javascript function from gmap.php, but it failed, because it's par of an onClick event and is part of a div, so the javascript doesn't parse properly. May you can think of a third solution. It seems like a easy thing in general, so I don't know why it doesn't work..

Comment: I should have noticed it before: You can not call load() directly, but after the page is finished, which is the onReadyStateChange event with readyState result (see my updated code) - that's why we call it asynchronous :-)